# Are Spring4 websockets supported in ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, websocket, spring-4

According to this document they are : http://caniuse.com/websockets

[image]

But this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673567(v=vs.85).aspx seems to suggest that the earliest version is ie10

Are Spring4 websockets (or web sockets in general) supported in ie8 ?

Update : Actually, I read that document http://caniuse.com/websockets) incorrectly, they are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

They are not supported as updated question states.